# Why would nslookup return a response, then timeout?

Tags: dns, systemd-resolved, nslookup

Here's what my nslookup is doing:

```
ubuntu@ca:~$ time nslookup focal-250
Server:     127.0.0.53
Address:    127.0.0.53#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   focal-250.test
Address: 128.8.8.187
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached



real    0m15.024s
user    0m0.005s
sys     0m0.018s
```

The first six lines (i.e, the correct response) printed instantly, then it waited 15 seconds to "time out".  Something like `ping` does the same thing: stalls for 15 seconds, then starts working.

It's an Ubuntu 20.04 LTS system running systemd-resolved.  The only thing weird about it is that it has `dnsmasq` listening for name service on one of its interfaces, and that interface's address is configured as its own nameserver:

```
ubuntu@ca:~$ resolvectl 
Global
       LLMNR setting: no                  
MulticastDNS setting: no                  
  DNSOverTLS setting: no                  
      DNSSEC setting: no                  
    DNSSEC supported: no                  
          DNSSEC NTA: 10.in-addr.arpa     
                      16.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      168.192.in-addr.arpa
                      17.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      18.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      19.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      20.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      21.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      22.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      23.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      24.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      25.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      26.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      27.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      28.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      29.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      30.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      31.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      corp                
                      d.f.ip6.arpa        
                      home                
                      internal            
                      intranet            
                      lan                 
                      local               
                      private             
                      test                

Link 3 (ens5)
      Current Scopes: DNS        
DefaultRoute setting: yes        
       LLMNR setting: yes        
MulticastDNS setting: no         
  DNSOverTLS setting: no         
      DNSSEC setting: no         
    DNSSEC supported: no         
  Current DNS Server: 128.8.8.254
         DNS Servers: 128.8.8.254
          DNS Domain: test       

Link 2 (ens4)
      Current Scopes: DNS         
DefaultRoute setting: yes         
       LLMNR setting: yes         
MulticastDNS setting: no          
  DNSOverTLS setting: no          
      DNSSEC setting: no          
    DNSSEC supported: no          
  Current DNS Server: 192.168.1.1 
         DNS Servers: 192.168.1.1 
          DNS Domain: freesoft.org
```

```
ubuntu@ca:~$ ip -br addr
lo               UNKNOWN        127.0.0.1/8 ::1/128 
ens4             UP             192.168.4.183/24 fe80::e2c:d2ff:fe67:0/64 
ens5             UP             128.8.8.254/24 fe80::e2c:d2ff:fe67:1/64
```

```
ubuntu@ca:~$ tail -5 /etc/dnsmasq.conf 
listen-address=128.8.8.254
bind-interfaces
dhcp-range=128.8.8.101,128.8.8.200,12h
dhcp-authoritative
domain=test
```

```
ubuntu@ca:~$ tail -4 /etc/resolv.conf 

nameserver 127.0.0.53
options edns0 trust-ad
search test freesoft.org
```

It's doing what I want, which is to answer queries for the ".test" domain, but I don't understand why it stalls for 15 seconds after getting the answer.

Comment: Try using something that gives you more information, like `dig`, and post the response.

Comment: @brunson, dig works fine pointed at either 128.8.8.254 or 127.0.0.53.  No delay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`nslookup` will query for both A and AAAA records, so if the A query returns immediately and the AAAA never returns, then `nslookup` will print an immediate response, then timeout.

Here's a table I made of how the `dnsmasq` server on 128.8.8.254 answered various types of queries:

```
dig @128.8.8.254 A focal-250          immediate success (A record)
dig @128.8.8.254 A focal-250.test     immediate success (A record)
dig @128.8.8.254 AAAA focal-250       immediate SERVFAIL
dig @128.8.8.254 AAAA focal-250.test  15 second timeout, no response
```

What the output from `nslookup` meant is that it got the A record response (the first six lines), then timed out waiting for AAAA record.

One way I found to "fix" the problem is to tell `dnsmasq` that it's authoritative for the `test` domain by putting `auth-zone=test` in its config file.  Now it behaves like this:

```
dig @128.8.8.254 A focal-250          immediate success (A record)
dig @128.8.8.254 A focal-250.test     immediate success (A record)
dig @128.8.8.254 AAAA focal-250       immediate SERVFAIL
dig @128.8.8.254 AAAA focal-250.test  immediate NOERROR (no records)
```

`nslookup` and `ping` now respond immediately.

I've also found it useful to make `dnsmasq` "authoritative" for `in-addr.arpa`, for the same reason: so it returns an immediate NOERROR instead of timing out.  The `systemd-resolved` service seems to use the answer from the server that responded with a record instead of the server that responded with nothing:

```
ubuntu@ca:~$ dig +short @128.8.8.254 -x 18.165.83.71
ubuntu@ca:~$ dig +short @192.168.1.1 -x 18.165.83.71
server-18-165-83-71.iad55.r.cloudfront.net.
ubuntu@ca:~$ dig +short @127.0.0.53 -x 18.165.83.71
server-18-165-83-71.iad55.r.cloudfront.net.
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that nslookup has 3 retries and 5 seconds timeout. That would explain the 15 seconds delay. You could verify by starting `nslookup` in interactive mode (just type that name and press enter). In that mode you write `set all` and you get a list of all the options (and their values) used by `nslookup`. That might be the easy part.

You say that the `nslookup` gets you the correct answer, yes, but the DNS server contacted (the one in /etc/resolv.conf) `127.0.0.53` is not the one answering. The answer is coming from the `dnsmasq` server at 128.8.8.254, as the address in the answer is an address in the range of that DHCP server.

Unless you have the address for `focal-250.test` in the `/etc/hosts` file. Which you don't seem to have. So, from the point of view of `nslookup`, the address request sent to `127.0.0.53` goes unanswered and it is configured to retry.

The difficult part is to explain how the server from `systemd-resolved` works. If the domain name is fully qualified, in other words, it has several dots, like `example.com`, the resolution is simple, it is just sent to the upstream DNS server(s), which are `128.8.8.254` **and** 192.168.1.1 (I assume this is your local router) as given by the command `resolvectl`. But if the name has no dots, as the name you used `focal-250`, the resolution **may** go first to LLMNR, MulticastDNS and/or Avahi systems and, if not resolved, go to the normal DNS servers. Please read the [point 4.1 in here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Systemd-resolved#mDNS) for a very short look into the issue.

In short, you should detect (and ensure) that short names are being resolved by the DNS server that you actually want to resolve them. A `dig @128.8.8.254 focal-250`, `dig @192.168.1.1 focal-250` and `dig @127.0.0.53 focal-250` should tell you which one is successful and gives the correct answer.

Note that: There is a misconfiguration for the interface `ens4` somewhere as the bridge address is set to `192.168.4.183` but the DNS server in that interface is set to `192.168.1.1`.